# Cannot use vue-start-rating in nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Cannot Used vue-star-rating in nuxt.js ReferenceError
document is not defined

```
<template>
      <star-rating v-model="rating"></star-rating>
</template>

import StarRating from "vue-star-rating";
    export default {
      components: {
        StarRating
      }
    }
```

thi is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-kilby-dkfys?file=/pages/index.vue)

Comment: Can you setup a codesandbox or a fiddle? anything that allows us to see the error

Comment: @painotpi https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-kilby-dkfys?file=/pages/index.vue this is codesandbox link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `vue-star-rating` does not support SSR, however, there is a [feature-request](https://github.com/craigh411/vue-star-rating/issues/31) open for this.

Currently, the only way to get this working with nuxt is to downgrade `vue-star-rating` to `1.6.2` and wrap it in `no-ssr` tags,

```
<no-ssr>
  <star-rating :rating="3"></star-rating>
</no-ssr>
```

Comment: The solution didn't work for me

Comment: it worked before..
but not now..

Answer (score 0):

The solution above didn't work for me.
So, I just took the library (2 components and 1 class) and moved it to my component folder, so the components support the SSR now.